# Write OS in interpreted language

Tags: compiler-construction, operating-system, interpreter

Is it possible to write an OS using a language that is not compiled [i.e. interpreted like python] or does not use a runtime [like Java] ? Wouldn't the virtual machine need to run on top of an OS already ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Microsoft Research has created an OS, called [Singularity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/singularity/).

It IS a research project though, and I think they needed some low level code to initiate the boot process (at some point an OS needs to talk to the hardware).

[Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_%28operating_system%29):

> The lowest-level x86 interrupt dispatch code is written in assembly language and C. Once this code has done its job, it invokes the kernel, whose runtime and garbage collector are written in Sing# (an extended version of Spec#, itself an extension of C#) and runs in unprotected mode. The hardware abstraction layer is written in C++ and runs in protected mode. There is also some C code to handle debugging. The computer's BIOS is invoked during the 16-bit real mode bootstrap stage; once in 32-bit mode, Singularity never invokes the BIOS again, but invokes device drivers written in Sing#. During installation, Common Intermediate Language (CIL) opcodes are compiled into x86 opcodes using the Bartok compiler.

Comment: What? IL is not interpreted in Singularity.

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  Just don't expect it be fast, which is why nobody does this.

You'll  likely have to do some funny things (virtual instructions) in the interpreter to allow your OS to make changes to the machine state (registers and stack, memory map, I/O device registers), and something machine specific to allow hardware interrupts to transition into execution of interpreted code, and back out to return from interrupts.  And you may have a rough time with the initial boot logic; your interpreter clearly can't load itself off the disk.

But for most of the OS, if done right, e.g, with a JIT compiler, it would be pretty portable and might actually be reasonably fast.  [You'd want the JIT compiler to be coded in the same language, and subject to self-JITting].

I proposed a C-like HLL that compiled to virtual machine interpreted code, in exactly this architecture for the OS 360 system back in the 1980s, and almost closed a deal to build it.  Would have been fun.  Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, specialty if you think in a virtual machine.

For example, you can create a small version of minix in java to run in the top of JVM. But I don't know the reason for someone do this, except too much free time :)

One operational system needs to be very thin and fast. If you choose python, you have the python interpreter overhead in each operation. Even if you think in a small part of the sytem, like device drivers: imagine the python interpreter running in kernel space for a while...

but for educational or special cases (arduino? embed?) it can be acceptable. I think lua can be a good idea because the interpreter is very small.

Answer (score 0):

There is a huge number of the homegrown Forth OSes. Forth is sort of on a borderline of being "interpreted" (but I'd prefer to stay away from this term, it is too vague and too widely misused).

Answer (score 0):

Every language/compiler utilizes some runtime, except for raw machine code. For example C has this thing called crt0, which is a set of execution startup routines for any C program. Not to mention the widely used libc. And so you cannot avoid it, the correct question is: how big/efficient a runtime should be? And how it should behave? For example: do I need a garbage collector?

Now some critical pieces of OS have to be compiled to the raw machine code. Otherwise CPU won't know how to execute it. After all CPU understands machine code only. Furthermore it has to follow a booting process, meaning the compiled code has to be compatible with bios or uefi or whatever you use for booting. Finally to take advantage of all/most CPU features some raw machine code has to be either emitted at compile time or jitted at runtime. For example CPU cores. While technically not necessary, you probably don't want an OS that doesn't know how to use multiple CPU cores.

Then you can do pretty much anything you want. For example you can embed a Java runtime inside your custom OS and let only Java programs to run in it. Still you probably will need some lower level language in order to implement some low level functionalities like hardware drivers.

Note that technically all of that can be written in any language. Even if your OS is Java based in can be entirely written in Python. At the end of the day an operating system is just a sequence of bytes which any language can emit. Although writing everything from scratch in, say Python, is a hardcore idea that I wouldn't recommend.